# Why can I not connect to my socket.io server?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, alpine-linux

I have a socket.io server running on an alpine linux docker image. I can connect to the socket on port 8080 via an html client, but if my Android or iOS apps try to connect they fail at the handshake.

I read something about linux automatically allows a proxy connection to /node, but /socket proxy has to be setup in a special way. Possibly a reverse proxy thing? I have this same server running on an AWS EC2 ubuntu classic instance and it works perfectly.

Here is the .conf file

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:websocket]
command=/usr/bin/node /srv/app.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/srv/logs/websocket.err.log
stdout_logfile=/srv/logs/websocket.out.log
```

Server:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
    return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
  };
}

function log_me(msg){
  var ts = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*4));
  var tss = ts.toString();
  tss = tss.substring(0, tss.indexOf(' GMT'));
  console.log(tss + ": " + msg);
}

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.set('log level', 2);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('join_channel', function(channel){
    log_me("join_channel: " + channel);
    socket.channel = channel;
    socket.join(channel);
  });


  // kue
  socket.on('proceed', function(channel, data){
    log_me("proceed: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('proceed', data);
  });
  // kue
  socket.on('instruct', function(channel, data){
    log_me("instruct: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('instruct', data);
  });
  // driver app
  socket.on('status_update', function(channel, data){
    log_me("status_update: " + channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('status_update', data);
  });
  // driver app
  socket.on('status_update2', function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    log_me("status_update: " + obj.channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(obj.channel).emit('status_update', data);
  });



  // requester and driver app
  socket.on('video_call_response', function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    log_me("video_call_response: " + obj.channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(obj.channel).emit('video_call_response', data);
  });
  // requester and driver app
  socket.on('video_call_hangup', function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    log_me("video_call_hangup: " + obj.channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(obj.channel).emit('video_call_hangup', data);
  });
  // requeter and driver app
  socket.on('request_video_call', function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    log_me("request_video_call: " + obj.channel + " - " + data);
    io.sockets.in(obj.channel).emit('request_video_call', data);
  });
  // anything that disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    log_me("disconnect: " + socket.channel);
    if(socket.channel){
      if(socket.channel.startsWith("a_")){
        var c = socket.channel.replace("a_", "");
        var data = {'ambulance_id' : c, 'status' : 'DISCONNECTED'}
        io.sockets.in(c).emit('status_update', JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    }
    socket.leave(socket.channel);
  });
});
```

Comment: *I can connect to the socket on port 8080 via an html client* - can you do that from Android/iOS too? (So not the app, but the browser)

Comment: Yes, but our apps don't use html browser views. They need direct socket connections I guess via TPC.